Same code working on Arduino IDE but not working on VSCode extension PlatformIO
I have a project on Arduino IDE that uses an ESP32, and it uses BLE and BT (Bluetooth). I decided to move my project to platfromIO using the VSCode extension as it is easier to manage and I copied my code and downloaded all the libraries with the same versions as the ones installed in the Arduino IDE. However, the code gives error on platformIO and these errors were not in Arduino IDE even though it is the exact same code.
The errors are Bluetooth related and they are from the ESP32-A2DP library https://github.com/pschatzmann/ESP32-A2DP. The Bluetooth still works with these errors, but I want to know why I am getting the errors.
[375094][E][BluetoothA2DPSink.cpp:414] app_send_msg(): [BT_API] app_send_msg app_send_msg failed
[376077][E][BluetoothA2DPSink.cpp:1114] av_hdl_stack_evt(): [BT_AV] esp_a2d_sink_init

What could be the reason for these errors?
My board is the ESP32-WROOM-32E
This is my platformio.ini file
[env:esp32dev]
platform = espressif32
board = esp32dev
framework = arduino
upload_speed = 921600
board_build.flash_mode = qio
board_build.f_flash = 80000000L
board_build.flash_size = 4MB
board_build.f_cpu = 240000000L
monitor_speed = 115200
platform_packages =
  framework-arduinoespressif32@https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32.git#2.0.11

lib_deps = 
    lennarthennigs/SimpleFSM@^1.3.0
    adafruit/Adafruit ADS1X15@^2.5.0
    xreef/PCF8574 library@2.3.6
    adafruit/Adafruit BusIO@1.14.5
  https://github.com/RobTillaart/AD5144A.git#0.2.0
  Wire@2.0.0
  SPI@2.0.0
build_flags =
  -Iinclude
  -D CONFIG_ARDUINO_RUNNING_CORE=1



different debug level?

@Juraj thank you, the errors were there in Arduino but the debug level was None, so I didn't see it before.
